# Controling an XD-40 LCUS USB relay

Tags: serial, relay, usb-device

I recently got a USB controlled relay which is designed to show up as a serial port on a PC, and accept commands. It's recognized just fine by my computer, but I can't seem to get it to actually do anything. This is my first time trying to use this kind of gadget, so I'm assuming I'm just missing something basic, but the unit came without a single scrap of documentation, so I'm hoping one of you fine folks can help me get things sorted out.

The device is an XD-40 LCUS, with a [CH340](http://wch-ic.com/product/usb/ch340.asp) chip on it, and the nearest thing to documentation I've found is the following, on one of the [sites online that sells them](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/XD-40-LCUS-1-type-USB-relay-module-USB-Intelligent-Control-Switch/1447853189.html):

```
Data (1) --- start logo (default is 0xA0)
Data (2) --- switch address code (default is 0x01, identifying the first way switch)
Data (3) --- Operating Data (0x00 to "Off", 0x01 "On")
Data (4) --- checksum

Example:
Open the USB switch: A0 01 01 A2
Close USB Switch: A0 01 00 A1
```

I had hoped to be able to pop open Putty, connect to COM4 (which is what my PC has decided to call the device) and go to town with the commmands listed above, but that's gotten me exactly nowhere, so I'm a bit confounded. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mikkel Those \xa0\x01\x01\xa2 and \xa0\x01\x00\xa1 strings also work great in realterm sent as an Ascii string. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Stumbled upon this post while trying to get a 4 channel version of this relay going. Found this and thought I should post for the next person. http://www.chinalctech.com/cpzx/32.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it isn't expecting an ASCII string like "A00100A1". Instead, it's expecting 4 raw bytes: `0xA0, 0x01, 0x00, 0xA1` (shown as hexidecimal).

You basically need to write a program to open the serial port, set it into "raw" mode so the OS doesn't try to change any bytes, and sent the four binary bytes. I could help you with Linux C code but it sounds like you're using Windows and I don't have the knowledge there.

Edit: See this [Superuser page](https://superuser.com/questions/338821/terminal-client-which-allows-sending-raw-bytes) for suggestions for sending raw bytes to a serial device.

Comment: That did it. Ended up using RealTerm, for anyone else who's trying to make this work. Sending those codes over as numbers (in the 0x hexidecimal format) worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this was a top hit in my search results, I'll chime in with the Linux commands that DoxyLover alludes to above.

Relay on:
`echo -en '\xa0\x01\x01\xa2' | sudo dd of=/dev/ttyUSB0`

Relay off:
`echo -en '\xa0\x01\x00\xa1' | sudo dd of=/dev/ttyUSB0`

Thank you for posting the hex codes in your question; it gave me a great starting point in getting everything working. The AliExpress link you gave is broken, and the unit I bought came with no documentation whatsoever.